# Angular: Template Driven Forms - Enable submit button if at least one field is entered

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I have a simple form that has a set of fields and I want to enable the submit button if at least one field has been entered. I don't wanna use a Model Driven Form as I feel it's a overkill, given the scenario.

What is the simplest way to check if at least one field is not empty in Template Driven Forms?

Answer (score 0):

You can work with **ngModel** and **ngModelChange**.

In your html:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="yourvalue" (ngModelChange)="valueChanged()" />
```

In your component:

```
private valueChanged(){
  // enable sumbit button
}
```