# Angular Template Driven Form: Validate at least one Filled

Tags: html, angular

I have a template driven form with multiple fields for searching in a table in angular. For this form, I would like to add a validation that checks that at least one input has been filled. It could then either enable the "search" button or display an error message if nothing has been put in. Either would work fine.

How can I add the said validation? I have looked up some similiar problems, but none would seem to work or fit the requirements.

[Other Stack Overflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46665522/angular-template-driven-forms-enable-submit-button-if-at-least-one-field-is-e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your field are bound with `[(ngModel)]`, you can simply disable to the search button if none are filled.
So if for instance your fields were `a` and `b` and each are bound to a field, you could disable the button based on conditions - `[disabled] = "!a && !b"` for as many fields as you have. Then, the search would only be enabled once a field had been filled in